# How to put an Alert for an empty field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to put an alert in my table when the user tries to add a new row (by clicking 'Add Button') without filling the current row.The user should not be able to add the row until and unless he fills all the columns in the last row.For adding the new row I am cloning the rows.Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
$(document).on('click','.Buttons', function() {
if($(this).closest("tr")==''){
alert("Please fill the current row");
return false;
}
    var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
    var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
    cindex++;
    $clone.find(':input').not('select').val('').attr('disabled', true);
    $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
    //update ids of elements in row
    $clone.find("*").each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            if(id != ""){

            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 2) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cindex);
            }
            }
    });
    $tr.after($clone);
});
 function disableField(){
    if(document.frmmain.fldsearch){
       $("input").prop('disabled', false);
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
      <thead>
    
        <tr>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
       <td class="headingalign" width="16%"></td>
    
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
        <tr id="id01" name="row">
     
          <td>
        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
        <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
              <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
              <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
              <option value="VID">Videos</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
            
          </td>
       <td>
       <input tabindex="6" id="Button4" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton" name="Button4" type="button" />
       </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
      <div class="buttonarea">
      <ul>
        <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
      </ul>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the issue/error you are facing?

Comment: I am able to add a new row without filling the previous column

Comment: how can anyone fill details if you generate input as disabled ?

Comment: Agreed with @DevsiOdedra , your inputs are disabled.

Comment: Yes when the user select the 'Select' field in the table ,the columns get enabled and then the user can fill the form

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the inputs from last *tr* whose values are empty:

```
var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
if(count || !$('select:last').val()){
  alert("Please fill the current row");
  return false;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
$(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(e) {
  var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
  if(count || !$('select:last').val()){
    alert("Please fill the current row");
    return false;
  }
  var $tr = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
  var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
  cindex++;
  $clone.find(':input').not('select').val('').attr('disabled', true);
  $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
  //update ids of elements in row
  $clone.find("*").each(function() {
    var id = this.id || "";
    if(id != ""){
    var match = id.match(regex) || [];
      if (match.length == 2) {
        this.id = match[1] + (cindex);
      }
    }
  });
  $tr.after($clone);
});

function disableField(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id01" name="row">
      <td>
        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
          <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
          <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
          <option value="VID">Videos</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500"  class="objinputtext" value=""  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" class="objinputtext" value=""  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" class="objinputtext" value=""  />

      </td>
      <td>
      <input tabindex="6" id="Button4" value="Delete Row"  class="DeleteButton" name="Button4" type="button" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  
        <div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: That will miss validating the "select" element in the table row.

Comment: @MuraliNepalli, you are right, updated the condition in the answer, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each element if its empty or not by looping  over the result of closet.

Just add this code:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("*").each(function() 
{
   if(this.value==")
   {
     alert("Required details missing");
     return false;
   }
});
```

Instead of this :

```
if($(this).closest("tr")==''){
alert("Please fill the current row");
return false;
}
```